# Why DataFrame is not being sorted?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a DataFrame of shape (3000,6) with one of the columns as 'id' (varies from 1-3000). Now I want to arrange this DataFrame in asscending order as per its id.

But when I use:

```
txt3=txt3.sort_values(by=['id'])
```

The Output is:

```
        id   mol type           x           y           z
27804     1     1    2     2.23235     10.7284     30.0676
29515    10     4    2     28.7113     18.5291     14.1294
28539   100    34    2     2.00022     28.4198     24.3493
29067  1000   334    2      20.349     12.0305      12.956
29058  1001   334    1     20.3903     12.1058     11.9597
29069  1002   334    1     21.2226     11.6872     13.3009
29006  1003   335    2      18.293      9.3888      6.5151
28980  1004   335    1     17.8874     8.91059     7.29408
29000  1005   335    1     17.7994     10.2436     6.35495
29932  1006   336    2     17.5695     25.0132      20.647
29927  1007   336    1     18.4396     25.0541     20.1559
29931  1008   336    1     16.9211     25.6502       20.23
28671  1009   337    2     26.8011      3.5409     1.93363
28531   101    34    1     1.43017     29.2102     24.5735
28676  1010   337    1      27.265     4.42643     1.95848
28653  1011   337    1     27.4619     2.82462     1.70935
27889  1012   338    2     2.60491     15.7642     3.00552
27898  1013   338    1     3.36353     16.4004     3.14608
27910  1014   338    1     2.04439      16.078     2.23912
27217  1015   339    2     3.74816     1.98577     14.7842
27206  1016   339    1     3.49939     2.80818     14.2725
27235  1017   339    1     3.33974     2.02428     15.6961
27701  1018   340    2     6.21727     12.6766     15.6722
27659  1019   340    1     6.13695      13.431     15.0206
28535   102    34    1     2.16946     27.8852     25.1773
.
.
.
27488    97    33    2     4.44905      11.874     3.34721
28625   970   324    2     17.1421     5.41548     4.56133
28628   971   324    1     17.1668     5.21626     5.54098
28626   972   324    1     17.4228     6.36274     4.40665
28971   973   325    2      18.374     13.2464     3.41594
28972   974   325    1     19.0354     12.5748     3.08197
28984   975   325    1     18.8416     13.9164     3.99252
27787   976   326    2     5.59809     8.30059     26.8862
27769   977   326    1     5.24029     8.93868      27.568
27430   978   326    1     4.97766     7.52092     26.8014
28614   979   327    2     22.2046    0.888559     3.38418
27494    98    33    1     5.27169     11.9811     2.78884
29817   980   327    1     21.7071     30.9472     3.58442
28612   981   327    1     21.9506     1.21747     2.47463
29390   982   328    2     24.7353     22.3862     6.90935
29414   983   328    1     24.6943      21.388     6.86549
29387   984   328    1     23.8691     22.7401     7.26229
29389   985   329    2     16.4165     16.1051    0.679083
29377   986   329    1     17.3629      16.107     1.00196
28979   987   329    1     15.8184     15.7589     1.40187
27665   988   330    2     15.5018     10.0054     13.3049
27632   989   330    1     15.1245     10.4035     14.1411
27486    99    33    1     3.63923     12.0209     2.77922
29066   990   330    1     16.2207     10.6012      12.947
27679   991   331    2     3.58923     13.4537     18.8384
27681   992   331    1     4.41859     13.9906      18.993
27667   993   331    1     3.82106     12.6183       18.34
29825   994   332    2     19.5436     29.8676     12.5336
29829   995   332    1     19.1367     29.3811     13.3068
29823   996   332    1     19.8106     29.2098     11.8293
29360   997   333    2      16.137     20.1473    0.335381
29372   998   333    1      15.641     19.5791    0.991946
29722   999   333    1     15.4968     20.7652     30.7815
```

What should I do to get this in completely asscending order by='id'.
P.s- I have also tried setting id as index and then using sort_index().

Comment: Looks like id is a string, so it's sorting alphabetically. Convert to int first.

Comment: @DYZ it's working. Thanks a lot!